# What can be done to make programs startup faster?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, performance, startup

I bought a new MacBook Air with an M1 chip.
When I launch programs, they don't launch immediately. First, the icon bounces for a few seconds, and only after that, I can see the program window.

I found a nice [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/8JwFkmqvRMA?t=134) that clearly shows the essence of this problem.

Here you can see the timer. It clearly shows that it takes **11 seconds to start** the program (VS Code), as well as mine.
The author of this video suggests downloading a special version of VS Code for the M1 chip. I did and it really helped a lot. But all other apps still take a very long time to load.

It makes me feel like I'm hitting something every time. **These delays are annoying, stopping my work, and I spend a lot of energy trying to make sure that my click finally gets a response**.

I believe the M1 chip is very powerful and fast. So it's probably some kind of animation, not a heavy task for the processor. I want programs to launch immediately when I click on them, without any delays, any animations.
What can be done to make my MacBook Air fast?

Edit #2:
Activity monitor:
[image]

[image]

SpeedTest:
[image]

Comment: This seems to ask at least two questions, namely "why is application startup slow on M1" and "why is this AppleScript slow". This site works better with one question per post, so please edit this accordingly. You can always ask the other question separately.

Comment: Having said that: All non-M1 applications need to be converted to ARM code *once* upon startup, so this might explain the delay you are seeing when launching applications. But this should go away the second time you run time. And in general, it's advisable to update existing applications so you get native ARM code binaries.

Comment: Also, if you look at the CPU view in Activity Monitor, what do you see there?

Comment: @nohillside I am new in MacOS. Can you explain in more detail what I should do to convert programs to ARM code? (all my app are already updated). Activity Monitor shows idle 98% permanently, and when I start any program the blue line (user usage) jump up to 30-60% for few seconds. And after program running blue line goes down again.

Comment: Intel-only applications are converted the first time you run them, they should launch significantly faster afterwards (about the same speed difference as running the old and the new version of VScode). But if this is your first Mac and you installed all applications directly via the Store or from the vendor, it's unlikely you have many Intel-only binaries installed.

Comment: Your question is still a bit unfocused. I reckon you will be able to get better help if you go by a single app. Among those you use most frequently, which app is launched with most delay and how long does it take for it to be launched after you click on its icon? Which macOS is installed on your Mac? On an other note, for most apps, you don't need to do anything special other than downloading and installing the recent macOS versions of the apps for them to work properly. And if you download an app's non-macOS version by accident, you will most probably not be able to install it on your Mac.

Comment: AppleScript is also a very high-level scripting language, and not known for its speed.   I usually find that python is pretty fast on Macs.

Comment: @benwiggy I run the AppleScript code on my M1, it more or less immediately created the file. But let's focus on the app startup issue for now.

Comment: @nohillside I try to focus on 1 program, but the problem is not in a specific program, this happens with all programs. I could leave the app on (then I see a dot next to her icon) In this case, when clicked, the program appears on the screen immediately. But if I don't run the program beforehand, then it takes a very long time. I just took the default program Pages, after clicking I wait 10 second before something happens. What is the computer doing all this time? Except icon is bouncing. I can't preload all the programs, I'd rather run them one by one as needed

Comment: How much RAM do you have, how does the Memory Pressure in Activity Monitor look like? A screenshot might help here, as well as one showing the top CPU hogging applications in the CPU tab. Remember, you are our eyes as far as your Mac is concerned, we can only provide ideas based on what you share with us.

Comment: @TamilaAmbeon As far as I can see, there seems to be something wrong with your setup - it's not supposed to be like this. In those cases, it can help to create a new user account on the computer, and see if the problem persists on that user account. A full reinstall of macOS is ofcourse also a possibility. One question I would like to ask about your current setup: Do you in any way have limited or filtered internet access? - i.e. do you have Internet access at all on the Mac? is it firewalled/filtered/blocked by anything? - This type of problem could occur when blocking essential services.

Comment: @nohillside 8 GB ram, I make screenshots with memory pressure and cpu load, please look to new edit this post. I just noticed that it says "intel" in front of github and not apple, does that mean this program needs to be converted to ARM? How can I do this? And startup of github app is slow also

Comment: There is now an ARM build of Github Desktop.

Comment: Yes, any application showing „Intel“ in the „Kind“ column in Activity Monitor got converted. It may help to check on the website of the respective vendor whether they have an Universal or ARM/Apple Silicon version available.

Comment: As @nohillside said earlier, intel app-binaries get converted/recompiled/emulated (whatever the term is) the first time they run on a M1. They should load up much faster after the first time. Separately to the above conversion, all apps run slower the first time after booting your mac (regardless of intel/universal app binary). However, if you quit the app and then reopen it later in the same boot-session (i.e. you don't shutdown/restart your mac), it'll open much quicker since the operating system will allocate some memory for applications that were previously opened in the same boot session.